# How to add row name in the table

Tags: sql-server, toad

I have a table like this

```
EmployeeID    Gender     Manager
1             F          Y
2             M          Y
3             M          N
4             M          N
5             F          N
```

My desired table is like this:

```
           Male    Female
Manager    1       1
```

The query I wrote is :

```
SELECT 
  sum( IIF(Gender = 'M' and Manager= 'Y', 1,0)) as Male, 
  sum( IIF(Gender = 'F' and Manager= 'Y', 1,0)) as Female, 
 FROM Table
```

And I got:

```
Male    Female
1       1
```

But I really want the second row has its first column to be with 'manager'.
So anyone can help?

Comment: `SELECT N'Manager' AS WantedColumnAlias`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'Manager' AS Manager
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might want to just group by the `Manager` column:

```sql
SELECT
  Manager
  sum( IIF(Gender = 'M', 1, 0)) as Male, 
  sum( IIF(Gender = 'F', 1, 0)) as Female, 
FROM Table
GROUP BY
  Manager;
```